# file searching by keyword and permissions

Tags: linux, terminal

I have tried many different things and looked around in the "man" pages for "grep" and "find" but I am still lost. I need a one liner in a linux terminal.

Here is the prompt:

"Find all the files in the system with the name "passwd" and save a list of those you can access to a new file in your home directory."
Can anyone help?

Thx guys

Comment: You should show some of the many things you tried and explain how, specifically, they failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
find / -type f -name passwd -readable 2>/dev/null 1> ~/readable-passwd-files
```

`/` is the path where `find` starts looking for what is specified by the following arguments. `-type f` selects files (instead of directories, symbolic links etc.), `-readable` narrows the search further down to what you called "accessible", `2>/dev/null` redirects errors to a sink such that don't clutter your terminal, and `1> ~/readable-passwd-files` finally writes the regular output of the command into a file.

Comment: Thank you lubgr! This worked great and was what I needed. Also, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I'm happy to help. If an answer solved your problem, you might consider accepting it.